# I want to encrypt mp4 file in flutter to prevent sharing file . How can I encrypt file?

Tags: flutter

I developed flutter download video application. I want to encrypt this video file to protect sharing to other. How can I do?. Please give me suggestions.

Comment: There is no bullet proof way to prevent sharing of video files. If you own the videos, your best bet is to use some DRM solution. If you are doing any encryption, you have to do it on server side to benefit from it. Not in your flutter app.

Comment: @noobs maybe this help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59981337/how-can-i-encrypt-video-file-using-dart