# Flutter - How do I secure a video so it can only play in my App?

Tags: flutter, dart, security, encryption, video

I want to make an app with paid videos but I need to secure the video so it can only be played in my app and can't be played in any video app

any tips / basic examples to secure the video ? on dart flutter

Comment: You can obfuscate and harden your app and encrypt the video stream + apply DRM on the video. Search the internet for "android video drm encryption".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are referring to `encryption`. Your videos will need to be encrypt(by your app obviously) so they could only be played by the app which have the encryption `key` (so your app) to decrypt them.
By doing so only your app will be able to display and play the encrypted videos.

To do so you will need an encryption package like [encrypt](https://pub.dev/packages/encrypt).

Other post that may help you [How can I encrypt video file using Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59981337/how-can-i-encrypt-video-file-using-dart).

Hope this will be useful.